# XSLT group by and then copy child node by "n" number of times

Tags: group-by, duplicates

I need to group the company and the maximum number the node row can occur in the new node group is 3.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:decimal-format name="coerce" NaN="0"/>
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <!--Group by fields, can only group by 1 element each time-->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="Company">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Department">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <!--Create a variable for the row count-->
                    <xsl:variable name="Grpcounter" select="number(position())"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$Grpcounter &lt; 3">
                        <xsl:call-template name="Group">
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Group">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you pls update your xslt as follows:

replace:  `<xsl:template match="/root"> . . . </xsl:template>` with

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:variable name="grouped">
        <!--Group by fields, can only group by 1 element each time-->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="Company">
        <!--<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Department">-->
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="position() mod 3 = 1">
                <Group>
                  <xsl:call-template name="Group"/>
                </Group>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <Group1>
                  <xsl:call-template name="Group"/>
                </Group1>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <!--</xsl:for-each-group>-->
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$grouped/*" group-starting-with="Group">
          <Group>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/row"/>
          </Group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>    
      </root>
    </xsl:template>
```

to get your expected output. See [result](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7S)

Comment: if you don't want to keep the `<xsl:call-template name="Group"/>` then replace with `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`.